# Disable gridview scrolling

Tags: android, gridview, scroll

I have layout having expandablelistview. and in that, each child item is having gridview. but gridview is having own scrolling and expandablelistview is having also. so I must have to set fix length for all gridview but there are dynamic number of gridviews.

I found solution for single gridview from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682445/how-do-i-calculate-the-required-height-of-a-gridview-that-is-inside-of-a-scrollv).

```
private OnGlobalLayoutListener mOnGlobalLayoutGridListener = new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {

        Debug.e("", "onGlobalLayout is called");

        if (gridView != null && gridView.getChildCount() > 0) {

            gridView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(
                    this);

            // gridView.get

            View lastChild = gridView
                    .getChildAt(gridView.getChildCount() - 1);

            int rows = gridView.getAdapter().getCount() / numColumns;
            int extra = gridView.getAdapter().getCount() % numColumns;

            if (extra > 0) {
                rows++;
            }

            int height = (int) (lastChild.getMeasuredHeight() * rows);

            gridView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height));
        }

    }
};
```

`OnGlobalLayoutListener` does not reference to particular Gridview. so that I can not use this listener for all gridviews because all gridviews are having different-different number of items.

see here

[image]

can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK scrollable items inside another scrollable items will not work in Android.

Comment: I know, that is why OnGlobalLayoutListener is used to set end length of gridview. but i'm facing problem with multiple gridview. problem is how to manage multiple OnGlobalLayoutListener.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom GridView like this,then you don't have to set fix length for all gridview  :

public class GridlistView extends GridView{

```
public GridlistView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}


public void  onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec,int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int expendSpec=MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE>>2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expendSpec);
}
```

}

use the Gridlistview  in your xml;